# Select values which not in another table with Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

How this SQL query can be translated to Django ORM statement?

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM table1
WHERE field1 NOT IN 
(SELECT 2_field1 FROM table2);
```

Kindly help! :)

ps
`table1` and `table2` not bounded with `ForeignKey` or `ManyToMany`

Comment: Using that query in raw method causes a broken pipe if you have too many records

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using two QuerySets, as shown [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

```
inner_qs = table2.objects.all()
results = table1.objects.exclude(field1__in=inner_qs)
```

Comment: Thank you for link, never reach this part of page with API :) BUT - this method is not efficient. Raw SQL through Django takes like 0,5 secs in my case (including `fetchall()`), method with nested queries takes 5 secs

Comment: I have often found raw sql to be much faster for stuff like this ... especially if inner_qs is large ...  but there may be a way to do the equivalent as the raw sql, if there is I havent found it...

Comment: A slight improvement; which, in some cases, makes the difference:

`inner_qs = table2.objects.values_list('field1',flat=True)
results = table1.objects.exclude(field1__in=inner_qs)`

Although, you should use the QuerySet method `raw()`, if you want to do your query actually faster.