# Django ORM Query: How to get record that Not Exist in other table

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

How to achieve this `Raw SQL` query in Django ORM?: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=54b789698f4e504e18a648c5fa4666bc).

So I have 2 table, Table `user` and `payment`, i need to get the user_id that not have a record in `payment` table (see expected result):

Models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    nama_lengkap = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
class Status_Pembayaran(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000000, decimal_places=2,
```

`User table:`

[image: table user]

`Payment table:`

[image: paument]

`Result Expected`

[image]

Comment: Show your Django models

Comment: @ArakkalAbu question updated.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105660/select-values-which-not-in-another-table-with-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105717/7664493

```
inner_qs = Payment.objects.all()
results = User.objects.exclude(id__in=inner_qs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with:

```
User.objects.filter(status_pembayaran=None)
```

or more verbose:

```
User.objects.filter(status_pembayaran__isnull=True)
```